# How can I attach Visual Studio debugger to pulumi up

Tags: pulumi

I have a stack defined in TS and cannot understand what is going on.

Is there a way to attach Visual Studio Code debugger to pulumi?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There appears to be an open issue on this since May 2018.
Looks like there is still a lot of work to be done to enable this.

https://github.com/pulumi/pulumi/issues/1372

Answer (score 3):

My vscode version:

```sh
❯ code --version
1.63.0
7db1a2b88f7557e0a43fec75b6ba7e50b3e9f77e
x64
```

`package.json`:

[image: package.json screenshot with vscode debugger prompt]

Notice the "debug" prompt above the scripts section. In between lines 5 and 6. You can click that and vscode will open up a debug console. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use in javaScript Debug Terminal.
This can be found in the left panel of visual Studio Code, precisely the run option. This option offers a JavaScript Debug Terminal button, this will open a new terminal with attached debugger.
This work for me